# How to parse variable to layout

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I'm trying out Fat-Free Framework, and I do not now how to parse variables to my layouts.
Well somehow I do, but not the way I want. I know you can parse variables via routes, and then using set.
But I have this layout where I have some specific variables which needs to be in my layout, and these will always be there, like my title and other stuff.
But it doesn't make sense that I need to parse these for every route, is there some way to do this.

I did read all the documentation they have on [fatfreeframework.com](http://fatfreeframework.com) and searched trough google and this site, but I could not find anything specific.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hello David, thanks for your guidance, i will look trouhg your links.
But i allready told what i have tried, and that was parsing the variables for every route.
But the problem is that it gets very messy, and i think it's a wierd way to do it.
So i was thinking that there must be another way to do it.
And i was asking for a way to do it, because i could not find anything about it anywere.

Comment: Also, please RTFM: http://fatfreeframework.com/views-and-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when you say "parse", you mean "define". I'll assume your question is: "how to define variables so that they are accessible from templates?".

There are various ways to achieve this. The basic way is to define variables using `$f3->set()`, then to display a template in which the defined variables will be accessible. For example:

```
//index.php
$f3->route('GET /example1',function($f3){
  $f3->set('title','my title');
  $f3->set('stuff','my stuff');
  $tpl=\Template::instance();
  echo $tpl->render('index.html');
}};

//index.html
<h1>{{$title}}</h1>
<p>{{$stuff}}</p>
```

Now if you need variables commons to all routes, you can define them outside of the route scope:

```
$f3->set('title','my title');//$title will be accessible from all routes
$f3->set('stuff','my stuff');//$stuff also
$f3->route('GET /example1',...);
$f3->route('GET /example2',...);
```

If you have many of those common variables and you need the possibility to modify them without changing the code, you can define them in a [configuration file](http://fatfreeframework.com/framework-variables#configuration-files) (.ini format):

```
//index.php
$f3->config('cfg/commons.ini');
$f3->route('GET /example1',...);
$f3->route('GET /example2',...);

//commons.ini
title = my title
stuff = my stuff
```

Comment: it's `{{@title}}` (with @ not $)

Comment: Well both syntaxes work. I like to keep `$` when possible to underline the fact that F3 variables are nothing more than PHP variables (which was not previously the case in V2).

Comment: awesome. you should visit us in IRC more often ;)

Comment: That was indeed what i was looking for that time.
Though i ditched F3 and learned Laravel instead :) So i now work full time as a Laravel developer. 

But thanks for taking the time and answering my question, i never got around to check the answer before now.